# Google App - check if file exists already?

Tags: google-apps-script

i use this code in upload form (google scripts):

```
var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
```

however, i want to check if file exist with same name, then dont upload. How to do that?

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: Is it some language for Google Docs? are you sure you run it on Google App Engine?

Comment: here it is: https://script.google.com/intro

Comment: ok, i'm removing tag _google-app-engine_ then, as it unrelated to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that's simple enough. All you need to do is use the [getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) and the use the `hasNext()` to see if any files were found:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('name of file to upload')
var chk = file.hasNext()
if (chk === true) return 1
```

if a file with the name was found, then `hasNext()` will return `true`. That means that we need to stop the script. You can do `throw` instead of a `return`, but that is up to you. The whole thing can also be in one line

```
if DriveApp.getFilesByName('filename').hasNext() === true) return 1
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get 'name of file to upload'?  i use in upload code : http://pastebin.com/raw/V0rWj5tC   thanks!

Comment: First of all, one thing from the pastebin. On line 19 you have `return fileBlob` which stops everything before any uploads happen. To get the filename all you need to do is `var fileName = fileBlob.getName()`